# How to remove quotes around a list in Elixir

Tags: elixir

One of the operation in Elixir is returning me

```elixir
"[some_data1, some_data2]"
```

And I want to remove the quotes around the list i.e. I want my end result to look like this

```elixir
[some_data1, some_data2]
```

Comment: What operation does return it?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin File.read!(file_name) in elixir

Comment: `File.read!/1` returns a string. Maybe json decode might help, depending on what values are in the list.

Comment: To clarify the question: do you want to remove the quotes from a string, or parse a string into a list?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin using JSON decode helped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

data.txt:

```
[{:a, 2}, "hello", %{b: 2, c: 3}]
```

a.ex:

```
defmodule A do
  def get_term(fname) do
    {term, _binding} = Code.eval_file(fname, ".")
    term
  end
end
```

In iex:

```
iex(7)> c "a.ex"              
warning: redefining module A (current version defined in memory)
  a.ex:1
[A]

iex(8)> A.get_term "data.txt"
[{:a, 2}, "hello", %{b: 2, c: 3}]
```

[Code.eval_file/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html) -- evaluates the file contents...It returns the result of the last expression in the file.

The `binding` returned by `Code.eval_file/2` works like this:

data.txt:

```
a = 3
b = 4
"#{a} + #{b} = #{a+b}"
```

a.ex:

```
defmodule A do
  def get_term(fname) do
    {term, binding} = Code.eval_file(fname, ".")
    IO.inspect binding
    IO.puts binding[:a]
    term
  end
end
```

In iex:

```
iex(22)> c "a.ex"             
warning: redefining module A (current version defined in memory)
  a.ex:1

[A]

iex(23)> A.get_term "data.txt"
[a: 3, b: 4]
3
"3 + 4 = 7"
```

Comment: I think it should be noted that `Code.eval_file/2` will simply run the file as an Elixir script, meaning that any code in there will be executed as well. If this file can potentially be written to by a malicious actor it might become a vulnerability. In general, I would avoid it for exchanging or storing data and use some other serialization mechanism like maybe `:erlang.term_to_binary/1` and `:erlang.binary_to_term/1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with binary pattern matching:

```elixir
def dequote(input) do
  length = String.length(input) - 2
  <<"\"", unquoted::binary-size(length), "\"">> = input
  unquoted
end
```

Here's a way to do it with regular expressions:

```elixir
def dequote(input) do
  [dequote] = Regex.run(~r/\A"(.*)"\z/, input, capture: :all_but_first)
  dequote
end
```

Comment: Hmm, looking at the question again it seems the OP actually wants to parse a string into a list. This answer is about removing quotes from a string - which is what the OP asked for but maybe not what they wanted.